# C# MVC Response in old mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

In new .NET core I can do this for WEB API

```
Response.AddPagination(page, pageSize, totalUsers, totalPages);

public static void AddPagination(this HttpResponse response, int currentPage, int itemsPerPage, int totalItems, int totalPages)
        {
            var paginationHeader = new PaginationHeader(currentPage, itemsPerPage, totalItems, totalPages);

            response.Headers.Add("Pagination",
               Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));
            // CORS
            response.Headers.Add("access-control-expose-headers", "Pagination");
}
```

What to do in old `MVC5`? What to use instead of

```
Response.AddPagination(page, pageSize, totalUsers, totalPages);
```

Is ok with

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
```